# Select unmatched records from two tables with a filter on second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have 2 mysql tables a and b. I need to show all records in a that are not in b using a common column 'ID'. Normally this is pretty straight forward but my problem here is this: I need to put a where clause on table b because I'm not interested in all unmatched records just the ones that meet the table 2 where clause criterion:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Description 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID 
WHERE a.Inactive = 0 
AND b.Room = '101' 
AND b.ID Is Null
```

This returns nothing. However if I remove the `AND b.Room = '101'` part, it displays the expected results. But I need that condition because I need only unmatched records specific to a 'room' and not all unmatched records

Comment: `AND b.ID Is Null` means (because `LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID `) it will only select rows where `a.id` and `b.id` are null. Thats NOT very likely ___I would assume___

Comment: Do you have any records in table b where ID is NULL and room equal 101?

Comment: @Riggs `LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID ... WHERE b.ID Is Null` will select rows where a.ID is not null but does not have a match in b, unless I am missing something.

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @RiggsFolly it may not be right to say "NOT very likely. I get use it more often to avoid using `NOT IN ()` clause because subquery will be very non performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the conditions involving table `b` from WHERE to ON clause:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Description 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Room = '101' 
WHERE a.Inactive = 0 
AND b.ID Is Null
```

It'll find rows where a does not have a match in b (id matches **and** room number = 101).

Comment: Am i wrong in my [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049674/select-unmatched-records-from-2-tables-with-a-condition-on-the-second-table#comment104339851_59049674)